# How can I use javascript to change the colour of a row in a table relative to input into table data?

Tags: javascript, css, if-statement, html-table

Maybe using a script is a long and wrong option.

But I am making a table of players in football teams. I want each "position" in the table to have a different colour background. I could of course instead of a script assign different id/class and put into table row for each position one by one.

So for example, say I want all midfielders to have red background and all defenders blue background.

Example of table...

```html
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Club</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Height</th>
        <th>Weight</th>
      </tr>
      <tr class="defenders">
        <td>Pique</td>
        <td>Barcelona</td>
        <td>Defender</td>
        <td>190cm</td>
        <td>85kg</td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="midfielders">
        <td>Busquets</td>
        <td>Barcelona</td>
        <td>Midfielder</td>
        <td>195cm</td>
        <td>85kg</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

So in table we have a defender and a midfielder. I would like them to have different colour backgrounds.

I was thinking a javascript "if" function could work.

As in

if the td is midfielder the tr background is red
if the td is defender the tr background is blue.

Is there an easy way to do this and what would be the code?

Or best just to use a class in the tr itself?

thanks.

Comment: you can do it with css `.midfielders td{ }`

Comment: Thanks but i was looking for a shortcut instead of having to type in class each time. Whereby just typing position eg. Midfielder, in the <td></td> the script would know to make all <td> in that row a certain colour...maybe to complex a task for a simple thing?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if your real case looks exactly like this, but here you have a possible workaround without editing html.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
    const [,...rows] = document.getElementsByTagName("tr") // take all rows but first 

    for (row of rows) {
       // for each row get the third column content 
      let position = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[2].textContent
      
      // add style depending on the text content
      switch (position) {
        case "Defender":
          row.classList.add("defenders")
          break;
        case "Midfielder":
          row.classList.add("midfielders")
          break;
      }


    }
});
```

```css
.defenders {
  background-color: #7972b7;
}

.midfielders{
  background-color: #d68383;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Club</th>
    <th>Position</th>
    <th>Height</th>
    <th>Weight</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Pique</td>
    <td>Barcelona</td>
    <td>Defender</td>
    <td>190cm</td>
    <td>85kg</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Busquets</td>
    <td>Barcelona</td>
    <td>Midfielder</td>
    <td>195cm</td>
    <td>85kg</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```